# ios spinner not stopping upon stop command

Tags: ios, xcode, spinner

I have an ios spinner that becomes unhidden and starts when I call it to (when a user logs in), and should stop and go back to being hidden if it is successful or unsuccessful using the code:

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

However, for some reason, it just keeps spinning and therefore remains unhidden. I thought that something simple like this would only require the "spinner stop animating" method...
(by the way, I named the spinner "spinner")

Comment: use break points and check those line of codes are executing...

Comment: I'd say that you need to provide us with the code that you use on the indicator and then we will be able to help you out. It is in fact that simple to stop an activity indicator so that must mean that there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I do this:

```
// on main thread
-(void)spinnerStopAnimating {
    if ([self.activityIndicatorView isAnimating]) {
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

Here, I have my activity indicator initialized in the following way:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
}
```

And started in this way:

```
CGRect rect = self.frame;
self.activityIndicatorView.center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width /2.0, rect.size.height / 2.0);

[self bringSubviewToFront:self.activityIndicatorView];
[self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
```

This also positions the spinner in the middle of the view.